# .NET Core C# - Delete file in a symlink folder in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-access

I'm testing a web app locally that will be hosted in a Linux environment. For testing, I created a symlink folder using the administrator command-line and mklink /D. This link is set inside the wwwroot folder of my app and is linked to a directory in C:\Users\User\the_folder. Reason for doing this is because I will need to create a symlink on my linux server to a mounted block storage drive.

I'm able to write files and new directories to this symlink directory, but for some reason it won't allow me to delete a file. I AM, however, able to delete an entire directory along with its contents with System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, true);

To delete a file, I'm trying to use System.IO.File.Delete, but this returns an access denied error.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: When the file was created by the user, not the web app under C:\Users\User\, the web app does not have the right to write or delete the file. Don't link to a folder in a user profile...

Comment: Ugh, of course ... thanks, that did it.